# Enabling diagnostic settings for Azure Storage Account using PowerShell

Tags: azure, powershell

I am trying to write a PowerShell script to enable Diagnostic settings for Azure Storage Accounts and send the logs to log analytics. For each storage account you can enable diagnostic for the storage account itself, blob, queue, table and file. I need to enable it for all 5 and configure to log read, write and delete, then send these logs to a Log Analytic workspace.

Here is a quick screenshot of the settings I want to enable.

[image]

I found couple examples on how to enable diagnostic using set-azdiagnosticsetting  but they don't seem to work.

```
Set-AzDiagnosticSetting -ResourceId "Resource01" -Enabled $True
```

## Set-AzDiagnosticSetting: Exception type: ErrorResponseException, Message: Null/Empty, Code: Null, Status code:Forbidden, Reason phrase: Forbidden

Next tried a different set of script, Create the metric, settings then apply. This example was also obtained from the reference link below.

```
$metric = New-AzDiagnosticDetailSetting -Metric -RetentionEnabled -Category AllMetrics -Enabled
$setting = New-AzDiagnosticSetting -Name $DiagnosticSettingName -ResourceId $ResourceId -WorkspaceId $WorkspaceId -Setting $metrics
Set-AzDiagnosticSetting -InputObject $setting
```

The only reference I found was:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.monitor/set-azdiagnosticsetting?view=azps-6.0.0

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/essentials/diagnostic-settings?tabs=PowerShell

Any one have better references or experience doing this??

Comment: Quick Updates #1: I still havent been able to do this via Powershell but was able to enable diagnostic setting for a storage account using Terraform. following this this link.  

http://man.hubwiz.com/docset/Terraform.docset/Contents/Resources/Documents/docs/providers/azurerm/r/monitor_diagnostic_setting.html 

Still trying to figure out how to enable monitoring for the Blob, File and Tables...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The storage account and each storage(blob, file, queue, table) have different resource ids, so you need to use a loop to set the DiagnosticSettings for them, just use the script below, replace the values of yours, it works fine on my side.

```
$ResourceId = "/subscriptions/xxx/resourceGroups/xxx/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/joystoragev2"
$WorkspaceId = "/subscriptions/xxx/resourcegroups/xxx/providers/microsoft.operationalinsights/workspaces/joyana"
$DiagnosticSettingName = "testdia123"

$metric = New-AzDiagnosticDetailSetting -Metric -RetentionEnabled -Category AllMetrics -Enabled
$setting = New-AzDiagnosticSetting -Name $DiagnosticSettingName -ResourceId $ResourceId -WorkspaceId $WorkspaceId -Setting $metric
Set-AzDiagnosticSetting -InputObject $setting

$metric = New-AzDiagnosticDetailSetting -Metric -RetentionEnabled -Category AllMetrics -Enabled
$readlog = New-AzDiagnosticDetailSetting -Log -RetentionEnabled -Category StorageRead -Enabled
$writelog = New-AzDiagnosticDetailSetting -Log -RetentionEnabled -Category StorageWrite -Enabled
$deletelog = New-AzDiagnosticDetailSetting -Log -RetentionEnabled -Category StorageDelete -Enabled
$Ids = @($ResourceId + "/blobServices/default"
        $ResourceId + "/fileServices/default"
        $ResourceId + "/queueServices/default"
        $ResourceId + "/tableServices/default"
)
$Ids | ForEach-Object {
    $setting = New-AzDiagnosticSetting -Name $DiagnosticSettingName -ResourceId $_ -WorkspaceId $WorkspaceId -Setting $metric,$readlog,$writelog,$deletelog
    Set-AzDiagnosticSetting -InputObject $setting
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Set-AzDiagnosticSetting is no longer available in recent versions of pwsh. This can now be accomplished via

```
$ResourceId = "/subscriptions/xxx/resourceGroups/xxx/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/joystoragev2"
$WorkspaceId = "/subscriptions/xxx/resourcegroups/xxx/providers/microsoft.operationalinsights/workspaces/joyana"
$DiagnosticSettingName = "testdia123"

$metric = New-AzDiagnosticSettingMetricSettingsObject -Enabled $true -Category Transaction -RetentionPolicyDay 7 -RetentionPolicyEnabled $true
New-AzDiagnosticSetting -Name $DiagnosticSettingName -ResourceId $ResourceId -WorkspaceId $WorkspaceId -Metric $metric

$Ids = @($ResourceId + "/blobServices/default"
        $ResourceId + "/fileServices/default"
        $ResourceId + "/queueServices/default"
        $ResourceId + "/tableServices/default"
)
$Ids | ForEach-Object {
    $metric = @()
    $log = @()
    $categories = Get-AzDiagnosticSettingCategory -ResourceId $_
    $categories | ForEach-Object {if($_.CategoryType -eq "Metrics"){$metric+=New-AzDiagnosticSettingMetricSettingsObject -Enabled $true -Category $_.Name -RetentionPolicyDay 7 -RetentionPolicyEnabled $true} else{$log+=New-AzDiagnosticSettingLogSettingsObject -Enabled $true -Category $_.Name -RetentionPolicyDay 7 -RetentionPolicyEnabled $true}}
    New-AzDiagnosticSetting -Name $DiagnosticSettingName -ResourceId $_ -WorkspaceId $WorkspaceId -Log $log -Metric $metric
}
```