# Error while running Set-AzDiagnosticSetting command

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-diagnostics, service-principal

I created a Service principal in azure and assigned my service principal to the custom role which I have created with set of permission in that particular subscription.

With the service principal, I am able to create a key vault, Storage account, and function app and so on.

But when I execute this particular command

```
Set-AzDiagnosticSetting -Name $diagnosticLogsSettingsName -ResourceId $resource.ResourceId -StorageAccountId $diagnosticLogStorageAccount.Id -Enabled $true -Category $Categories -MetricCategory AllMetrics -RetentionEnabled $true -RetentionInDays 90
```

I am getting the following error

```
Set-AzDiagnosticSetting : Exception type: ErrorResponseException, Message: Null/Empty, Code: Null, Status
03:24:52   Error message: Set-AzDiagnosticSetting : Exception type: ErrorResponseException, Message: Null/Empty, Code: Null, Status
03:24:52   code:Forbidden, Reason phrase: Forbidden
```

Not sure why I am getting forbidden error

Could anyone Please help me to resolve the issue. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

One of the workaround you can follow to resolve the above issue;

Based on this [***GitHub***](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/blob/main/src/Monitor/Monitor/help/Set-AzDiagnosticSetting.md#examples) Blog

> *For example to enable all available metrics and logs for a particular*
> *resource (i.e,Resource01)*.
>
> ```
> Set-AzDiagnosticSetting -ResourceId "Resource01" -Enabled $True
> ```

***Alternatively***, *please find this* **SO THREAD**| [***Enabling diagnostic settings for Azure Storage Account using PowerShell***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67828278/enabling-diagnostic-settings-for-azure-storage-account-using-powershell) as suggested by ,@*Joy Wang* .

**We have tried with the suggested PowerShell script and it works fine**

***NOTE:-*** *Please make sure that we are providing the correct workspace ID(Log analytics workspace ID) and resource ID(Storage account resource ID)* .

***OUTPUT DETAILS FOR REFERENCE:-***
[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Able to resolve the issue By adding the following permission to my custom role.

```
Microsoft.Insights/diagnosticSettings/write
```

I came to know to add this permission by executing the following command in "-Debug" mode which will give a clear error with the missing permission

```
Set-AzDiagnosticSetting -Name $diagnosticLogsSettingsName -ResourceId $resource.ResourceId -StorageAccountId $diagnosticLogStorageAccount.Id -Enabled $true -Category $Categories -MetricCategory AllMetrics -RetentionEnabled $true -RetentionInDays 90 -Debug
```

So just need to add -Debug flag at the end of command